# LPSTR how to free memory after using

Tags: string, unicode-string

Suppose i have a LPSTR variable. How do i free the memory after using the variable. 
Is it

```
LPSTR szFileName = GetSBCSBuffer(sFilePath); // sFilePath is a CString
delete szFileName;
```

OR

```
delete []szFileName;
```

Kindly advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory was allocated using `new char[SIZE]` then it needs to be freed using `delete []`.

Comment: i dont explicitly allocate all i do is written in that code where getsbcsbuffer() function accepts a string and returns a char * something like this

 int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, str, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 // allocate the buffer to hold the converted string
 LPSTR result = new char[len];
 // do the conversion
 WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, str, -1, result, len, 0, 0);
 return result;

Answer (score 1):

You can't answer that question without knowing the specifics of GetSBCSBuffer.  Hopefully whoever wrote the function left you with code and/or documentation so you can see where the string comes from.  It might be that neither of your alternatives is correct.  The author of GetSBCSBuffer might have used a different memory allocator or returned a pointer to a location internal to sFilePath.  In the last case it would be very bad to call any deallocator.

I just noticed you answered the question yourself in your comment to [elder_george's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688278/lpstr-how-to-free-memory-after-using/1688594#1688594).  The implementation used new[] so you need to delete[].

Comment: int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, str, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0); // allocate the buffer to hold the converted string 
LPSTR result = new char[len]; // do the conversion WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, str, -1, result, len, 0, 0); 
return result;


This is what is written in getsbcsbuffer.

Comment: Sorry I put the answer in the original text because I don't know how to hyperlink in a comment (new at this).  You just posted that result is allocated using new char[len] so you must free it by using delete[] szFileName.  Always match new with delete and new[] with delete[].